# Encrypting in Java and Decrypting in Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, encryption, cryptography

I want to encrypt a string in Java and decrypt it Javascript. I tried `Crypto` in javascript, but decrypted incorrectly. What is the simplest way to decrypt in Javascript?

I used the encryption code from the following link:

http://bryox.blogspot.in/2011/12/encrypt-and-decrypt-string-by-java.html

Comment: It depends on the encryption. Provide us more informations and maybe we'll be able to help you.

Comment: We need the code on both ends.

Comment: No, you didn't. You haven't shown us what you tried. By the way, they code you are pointing to uses platform specific encoding (value.getBytes()), uses ECB instead of e.g. CBC, does not provide for integrity/authenticity required for encrypted communication and uses hex instead of base64 for the ciphertext (which is OK, but not very efficient).

Comment: Additionally, please take a look at this article: http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/

Answer (score 0):

> What is the simplest way to decrypt in Javascript?

Insecurely.

Alternatively, if you're looking for the simplest way to *securely* encrypt/decrypt in Java and Javascript, you might want to take a look at [libsodium](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/bindings_for_other_languages), which has bindings for [Java](https://github.com/terl/lazysodium-java) and [JavaScript](https://github.com/terl/lazysodium-java).

#### Encrypting in Java with LazySodium

```
LazySodiumJava lazySodium = new LazySodiumJava(new SodiumJava());
SecretBox.Lazy secretBoxLazy = (SecretBox.Lazy) lazySodium;

Key key = lazySodium.cryptoSecretBoxKeygen();

String msg = "This message needs top security";
byte[] nonce = lazySodium.nonce(SecretBox.NONCEBYTES);
lazySodium.cryptoSecretBoxEasy(msg, nonce, key);
```

#### Decrypting in JavaScript with Sodium-Plus

```
const {SodiumPlus, CryptographyKey} = require('sodium-plus');
let sodium;

async function decryptMessage(ciphertextHex, nonceHex, keyHex) {
    if (!sodium) sodium = await SodiumPlus.auto();

    let ciphertext = Buffer.from(ciphertextHex, 'hex');
    let nonce = Buffer.from(nonceHex, 'hex');
    let key = CryptographyKey.from(keyHex, 'hex');
    return sodium.crypto_secretbox_open(ciphertext, nonce, key);
}

decryptMessage(ciphertext, nonce, key).then((plaintext) => {
    console.log(plaintext.toString());
});
```